# Bash script is not inheriting its parent's env

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

An alternative title for this question would be:

> "command recognized in parent shell is not found in subshell"

I have this in a parent shell

```
source ~/.quicklock/ql.sh
```

and this command is recognized in my current shell:

```
ql_acquire_lock
```

then I run a script like so:

```
./script/tsc.sh
```

in that script we have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e;
ql_acquire_lock
```

I must be very confused about how shells work, because I thought a child shell/process would inherit the env of the parent, unless explicitly calling unset etc.?

Here is the error I get:

```
./scripts/tsc.sh: line 3: ql_acquire_lock: command not found
```

Comment: the command is a function, sorry should have specified that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A child shell will inherit the environment of the parent shell.

The environment will contain what is exported by the parent shell.

If your shell function is not exported, it will not exist in the child's environment.

A `bash` shell function may be exported for use in a `bash` child shell using

```
export -f functionname
```

in the parent shell.

Comment: nice thanks that works, I have export all the functions, even ones I'd like to keep private but o/w that's good.